# How can I safely delete data related to wp_post table manually from the mysql database?

Tags: database

Recently I downloaded a plugin that had a bug that orphaned its custom post type items in the wp_post table rather than deleting them. Being new to wordpress, it wasn't apparent to me that the wp_postmeta table was related to that table. Now, I have entries in the latter with NULL values for the $post_id. (I simply deleted everything in wp_post with that content type.)

I'm assuming that it would be easy enough to do a left join query to find all those wp_postmeta items and delete everything with $post_id NULL. But, I'm not exactly sure how the wordpress tables relate to each other. If I were to do this manually, are there any other default tables that need to be taken into consideration? Does anyone have a script in their library to  handle something like this?

If you can suggest a plugin, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that, did you contact the plugin author?  You can find the db diagram here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description  Make sure you make backups of your databases before you do major operations like that too!

Comment: Also the mysql workbench is free and it will reverse engineer database diagrams for you, I'd recommend you use that instead of phpmyadmin or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already deleted all the posts in the table, this is going to be quite a bit of work manually.

For the next time you do something like that, use `wp_delete_post( $postid, $force_delete );` ([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post)) while looping through all the posts with that posttype, as this function deletes all the data associated with that post.

```
$args = array(
    'posttype' => 'yourposttype',
    'numberposts' => -1
);
$todelete = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $todelete as $deletethis ) {

    wp_delete_post( $deletethis->ID, true );

}
```

In your case, you will have to check the following tables for data (I skip the tableprefix here):

- posts (which you already did)
- postmeta
- comments/commentmeta
- term_relationships

In all cases you will have to search for entries with the `post_id`/`object_id` NULL or with no entry in the posts table, and delete them. The SQL should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: great direction should I have to end up doing that again, and thanks for the heads up about the specific tables I need to watch out for!